# HTML & CSS Frameworks

Tags: html, css, frameworks

I'm a beginner web developer that has learnt all the basics in html and css. Currently, I've been introduced to the concept of frameworks to sort of ease the placement of elements in a web page.

In regards to this, I am still confused as to how do you implement them into your code. Whenever I download one, I get a bunch of files and don't know what to do with them. I'm surprised there aren't too many explanations online as to how to use them, maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.

Secondly, is there a beginner friendly framework I should start with? I've seen people suggest 960 Grid System.

In addition, what makes a framework "light"? What is the difference and what purpose does a "light framework serve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you must be a bit lost, like we are now on other subjects.

Go to this link:

[This is the code of 960 Grid System](http://grids.heroku.com/fluid_grid.css?column_amount=12)

You have to copy the whole content of the link.

In your current web, you are going to have a main HTML file (probably index.html or like that). In the same folder where your main HTML file or index is, create a folder called CSS and inside this one, create a file called for example grid960.css. Now, open it, copy all the content of the link and paste it in your grid960.css file. Save it, and in your main HTML file, you have to call it to make it work. For that, in your HTML head section, copy this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid960.css">
```

Now you can use it. And you have to know that the best way to use it is applying its classes with divs. To explain some of the classes grid960.css has, I am going to give you an example:

```
<div class="container_16"> <!--The other option is container_12.-->
   <div class="grid_8">
      This div is going to occupy half part of the window.
   <div>
   <div class="grid_4">
      This div is going to occupy a quarter of the window.
   <div>
   <div class="grid_4">
      This div is going to occupy a quarter of the window.
   <div>
</div>
```

You can also do this:

```
<div class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_12">
      This div is going to occupy the whole window. Next grid you put is going to be below it because is not going to fit.
   <div>
   <div class="prefix_2 grid_8 suffix_2">
      This div is going to occupy the whole window too, but with a margin-left (prefix_2) with the same width of a div of class grid_2, and the same for the margin-right (suffix_2)
   <div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can do combinations:

```
<div class="container_16">
   <div class="prefix_1 grid_7 suffix_8">
   </div>
   <div class="prefix_6 grid_10">
   </div>
</div>
```

And whatever you want. Try it. It is very easy. I hope I have helped you.